# What is this on my cats lip?

Tags: cats, health

[image]

**I don’t know what this is on my cats lip 
It’s been here about 5 Days**
I am worried 
I am going to take her to the vet when I get paid 
Just want to know if it’s ok for the time being

Comment: please update your post after the visit to your vet as it might be helpful to know what it is for other pet owners.

Comment: @olivia Could you indicate which area you mean, to me nothing looks much out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 2):

It does not look serious to me and as long as your cat show no sign of pain or changed behaviour it is not an emergency.

If your cat changes behaviour or stop eating for more than one day you need to take her to the vet as this can be a sign of problems.